# Laravel doesn't import/read public source files (css/js)

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, import

I'm working on an external project. The application is already written and I need to add some functionalities. That's why I can't edit the way they import CSS and js files in the code. Unfortunately, I can't access the js and CSS files at my localhost

Importing like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/search-form/range-slider.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/provider-search.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/search-form/show-detail.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/slider-custom.css') }}">
<script src="{{asset('/js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
```

In my browser I see following errors:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

and that for every js/css file.. all my files are located at

```
public/css/name.css
public/js/name.js
public/js/init/name.js
public/js/search-form/name.js
```

The links to the sources seem right, so I think it's something to do with authorities but I'm very new in Laravel.

Comment: Normaly files that exist in your public folder are not served by laravel. They should be served by your webserver e.g. nginx/apache (or `php artisan serve`).

Comment: Btw you show the error for `tooltipster.bundle.min.js` but don't show where the file is or how you echo it in a `script` tag.

Comment: are you able to access file with full path without using laravel way??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{ URL::asset('css/name.css')}}"></link>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/name.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/init/name.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/search-form/name.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/search-form/range-slider.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/provider-search.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/search-form/show-detail.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

Make your directory structure is like this for JS:

```
/public/js/search-form/range-slider.js
/public/js/provider-search.js
/public/js/search-form/show-detail.js
/public/js/scripts.js
```

**For CSS:**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/slider-custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Make your directory structure is like this for CSS: `/public/css/slider-custom.css`